# Tobit regression in R with fixed effects - warnings or errors

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis

I am estimating a standard Tobit Model with a large panel dataset. I need to include fixed effects by ID and TIME, but using either AER::tobit() or VGAM:vglm() runs into issues with the optimization. The problem seems to be with inverting the design matrix.

For example, AER::tobit() and VGAM:vglm() run fine for tobit.AER and tobit.vglm for the below sample code. But once I add the factor variable `as.factor(id)` the optimization either fails (AER) with or produces warnings (VGAM).

The errors are:

> Error in solve.default(vcov.hyp) :
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.00879e-17

and

> In checkwz(wz, M = M, trace = trace, wzepsilon = control$wzepsilon) :
> 16 diagonal elements of the working weights variable 'wz' have been replaced by 0.000000000001819

As a result, AER::tobit stops and VGAM:vglm is for all practical purpose stuck (when running on my actual large dataset).

It doesn't seem that I can chose a different optimization method with either of these packages (AER is relying on `survreg` and VGAM has its own optimization routine based on Fisher Scoring).

Is there another way to code this?

Thank you!!

````
n <- 1000

res <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
int <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(10,n/2)) 
id  <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(1,n/2)) 
X   <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

y.star <- int + 4*X + res
y <- if_else(y.star >= 0, y.star, 0)

test.data <- data.frame(factor(id), y, X)

summary(tobit.AER    <- AER::tobit(y   ~ X,                  left = 0, cluster = id, robust=TRUE, data = test.data))
summary(tobit.AER.fe <- AER::tobit(y   ~ X + as.factor(id) , left = 0, cluster = id, robust=TRUE, data = test.data))

summary(tobit.vglm    <- VGAM::vglm(y   ~ X ,                 VGAM::tobit(Lower = 0, type.fitted = "censored"), robust=TRUE, data = test.data))
summary(tobit.vglm.fe <- VGAM::vglm(y   ~ X + as.factor(id) , VGAM::tobit(Lower = 0, type.fitted = "censored"), robust=TRUE, data = test.data))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the design matrix becomes problematic when including fixed effects for large panel datasets and leads to the issues you have highlighted above.

Try using the *within-group* transformation, which involves subtracting the group means from each observation within each group (i.e., for each ID and TIME combination). This transformation eliminates the need to include fixed effects in the model and can help to reduce the dimensionality of the problem.

```
library(plm)

n <- 1000
res <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
int <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(10,n/2)) 
id  <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(1,n/2)) 
time <- rep(1:2, n/2)
X   <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

y.star <- int + 4*X + res
y <- if_else(y.star >= 0, y.star, 0)

test.data <- data.frame(id, time, y, X)

tobit.plm <- plm::pgmm(y ~ X, data = test.data, index = c("id", "time"), effect = "twoways", model = "tobit", lower = 0, display = "summary")

summary(tobit.plm)
```

Comment: Thank you @Next Door Engineer for the suggestion. 

I am not sure plm() can handle a Tobit model. Here is what I get when running your suggestion:

```> tobit.plm <- plm::pgmm(y ~ X, data = test.data, index = c("id", "time"), effect = "twoways", model = "tobit", lower = 0, display = "summary")

Error in match.arg(model) : 'arg' should be one of “onestep”, “twosteps”```

Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: For what it is worth, the equivalent command (without requesting robust errors) in Stata ```tobit y x i.id, ll allbaselevels``` runs through without any warnings or errors.