# How to efficiently run Tobit model in R with time and geographic unit fixed effects?

Tags: r

Normally for OLS, probit, logit models I use the wonderful `fixest` package in R. However, it seems this package does not support Tobit estimations. I Googled extensively, including finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758086/tobit-regression-in-r-with-fixed-effects-warnings-or-errors) thread which asks a similar question about Tobit in R, but I have unfortunately not found a good package or function for computationally efficient Tobit estimation. Would prefer not to have to do this in Stata given my current project setup.

I have primarily been using the `tobit()` function from `AER`, since after doing some benchmarking it seems it runs faster than `censReg` and roughly the same as `vglm()` from `VGAM`. Rather than a separate argument for fixed effects like in `fixest`, my current Tobit model using `tobit()` includes time and geographic unit fixed effects as independent variables in the model with `i(time)` and `i(geographic unit)` fixed effects. This takes ~3 hours to run on 16GB RAM machine with 160,000 observations, 16 time periods, and ~900 geographic units. Also, when printing results with `summary()` or exporting results using `texreg()`, the output includes an unwieldy amount of coefficient estimates.

In comparison, when running a similar OLS specification in `fixest` using `feols()`, and interacting the time and geographic unit fixed effects (which I have been unable to do using `tobit()`), the estimation executes in fewer than 10 seconds. Plus it is easy to print the estimation results without coefficient estimates for each unique fixed effect value.

Can anyone share guidance for how to run Tobit more efficiently in R using fixed effects, either in `AER` or some other package? And/or how to cleanly print results? Thank you.